# Defining a 128-bit integer in C

Tags: c, type-conversion, bit-manipulation, 64-bit, bit

To represent this value, I am following the definition:

```
#define NUM_BITS 128
typedef unsigned char BigInt[NUM_BITS/8];
```

That is, a value of type BigInt must be represented by an array of bytes, interpreted as a single 128-bit integer, in two's complement and following the little-endian order.

For example, `{0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}`, which represents the integer value 1.

I've been thinking of doing a function like that:

```
void big_val (BigInt res, long val);
```

Which would be an attribution with extension. The big_val function assigns res the value provided by l (a signed long), correctly extended to 128 bits.

I was thinking of, for example, getting the most significant byte, getting the sign of the number, through `y = val & 0xFF000000;` and repeat this byte for another 8 times to form my array. But how could I get the bytes which represents the numbers without the signal?

That's what I've done so far:

```
void big_val(BigInt res, long val){
    long y;
    y = val&0xFF000000;

    for(int i = 8; i < 16; i++){
        res[i] = y;
    }
}
```

*(To anyone who has seen this post some minutes ago, I accidentally deleted it instead of editing, sorry)*

Comment: Consider what happens if `val` = `0x80000000`.

Comment: I have found that a byte array is convenient for when you want to keep a value as radix 10 (making it easy to output as text)  but otherwise to use an array of `uint32_t` so that you can use `uint64_t` for partial products, overflow etc. However that can still be kept 10-friendly by using a radix of 10^9 instead of 2^32.

Answer (score 1):

Assign byte by byte, one byte at a time.

```
void BigInt_init_from_long(BigInt res, long val){
    size_t i;
    bool negative = val < 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(long); ++i) {
        res[i] = val & 0xff;
        val >>= 8;
    }
    for (; i < NUM_BITS/8; ++i) {
        res[i] = negative ? 0xff : 0; // sign extension
    }
 }
```

Comment: Yu can probably get away with a `memcpy` in there instead of one of them there for-loops and bit-wise logic.  And an if-else with `memset` for the other.

Comment: The second loop may be replaced with memset. The first one cannot  be replaced with `memcpy` (on big endian machines).

Comment: Fair enough.  I wasn't considering architectural portability given we are making assumptions about CHAR_BIT and it being two's complement.  I figure they want little-endian order to fit their little-endian system.